# NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when user clicks a button

Tags: c#, winforms, nullreferenceexception, buttonclick

I have deployed my software to a few users around the world, and today one of them told me he got this error. I've never seen it when running the software on my own machine, and I've not gotten any other reports of it.

When the user clicks a standard button, he gets the following error text:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> at x.MainForm.btnCreateOutput_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

I'm not really sure what to make of this message.

In `btnCreateOutput_Click` I just do some string work, I don't use the parameters of the function for anything.

There are a lot of similar functions in the software, and the error only happens with this button apparently.

Comment: Please post `btnCreateOutput_Click` code.

Comment: It is probably most definitely not caused by a mouse issue. This error usually indicates that the error occurs within your btnCreateOutput_Click handler, which is why @dasblinkenlight has asked to see your code; a property or instance in that method is null.

Comment: May be i am wrong..just an idea from what i lived few months ago..
 Q1 - did you use obfuscation ? (i guess yess)
did you publish an update ? and was it has the option of "optimize code" ?

( may be all you alrready knew this but few weeks ago i discovered  that if optimize code option checked and used with obfuscation the first clicked item gives error something like this.. in my project main window is mdi and when menu clicked i took error )

and please check your customer's instance.. sometimes customers can be careless and accidentally deleted some requirement of the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem exists inside `btnCreateOutput_Click`, to see which line is responsible for exception you could attach .pdb's to installer, and you will get detailed information what file/line in your source is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

First of all catch the exception and get the specific error....

it might be because of connection string getting wrong and the connection object is not initialized (well if at all your application uses one...)..

Answer (score 0):

Enable first chance exceptions handling in `Visual Studio` and it will hit on *exact* line where the execption raises.

Look here:

[How to Enable First Chance Exceptions in Visual Studio](http://florianreischl.blogspot.it/2010/01/how-to-enable-first-chance-exceptions.html)

**EDIT**

If this happens **only** on client side, make use of handling of

[AppDomain.UnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

and log complete stack trace, with additional *your* debug information.

If it statistically happens on some particular client, what I would do (having already in hands the method where I got a problem) is to log all possible `null` conditions, and give that version to the client. After exception happened in the log file I would have definitely more information to work on.

I naturally assume that you can not debug an application on his side, also because exception happening in the event handlers often are in relation of behavioral model of the user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I do this, will I get more exception text from the user? I mean now it only says which method is "failing". And to be honest, I think I've already enabled this by the looks of it.

Comment: Problem exists inside click method. To see where exactly you could give user .pdb and you should get file/line wich is failing. You could also log to his computer via remote desktop for 3 min, to check yourself by using ie. Ammyy Admin ;)

Comment: @cichy: as I wrote I assume in my post that OP has no **any** "easy" access to the client machine or client time to make him to test it.

Comment: @Tigran i have read it. Eventualy he needs to take some of his clients time to find error, ie. by reinstalling application with new version with updated log. Why not attach .pdb's, and get full info then. Remote Access was only a partial solution to this which should help faster find where is the problem.

Comment: @Tigran I tried to use the UnhandledException event from your link, didn't give me more info on the exception unfortunately.

Comment: @cichy Using .pdb file gave me the info I needed, I got the exact line where the error occurred. Please make an answer and I'll approve...

Comment: @eightx2: considering that this exception doesn't happen **always** (according to a post) but *sometimes*, you need to investigate whta client does, in order to get to the point when in that event handler he gets exception. For this you need to log all possible conditions. By the way, if you have a possibility to access the client's machine, and/or make him to remake the problem, PDB suggested by CICHY is better choice. In **my** answer I assumed that you have no access and flexibility from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely: the problem is that you are trying to read or write a property or call a method for an reference for an uninitialized object

This is certainly not the mouse.

Comment: It's not the mouse? Maybe it's the monitor then... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

This might be an old question, but for those who struggle with this problem, another possible solution would be checking which .NET version is installed on the machine.

To be more precise, .NET 4.0 Client Profile isn't enough. Install the full .NET 4.0 and it should work now. Of course, if there aren't any flaws in your code.

It worked for me.

Comment: To be more precise, .NET 4.0 Client Profile isn't enough. Install the full .NET 4.0 and it should work now. Of course, if there aren't any flaws in your code. It worked for me. It's also worked in my case, just change .NET framework to 4.7 or higher